# Filling data down to subsequent row

Tags: r

I have data that look similar to:

```
Alabama Age>50 Value1 Value2 Value3
        Age<50 Value1 Value2 Value3
Alaska Age>50 Value1 Value2 Value3
        Age<50 Value1 Value2 Value3
```

I only need to keep the data for `Age<50`. How can I repeat the state name to the row below it? I have created a string of the state names, but am unsure how to insert it into every other row in the first column.

The head of my `data.frame` is:

```
d <- structure(c("ALABAMA", "", "ALASKA", "", "ARIZONA", "", "Under 18",
        "Total all ages", "Under 18", "Total all ages", "Under 18", "Total all ages",
        "0", "1", "10", "87", "46", "303", "0", "0", "0", "36", "6", "855", "84,843",
        "", "469,145", "", "6,303,555", ""), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL,
        c("State", "", "Rape3", "Prostitution and\ncommercialized\nvice",
        "2014\nestimated \npopulation")))
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843887/in-r-merge-two-data-frames-fill-down-the-blanks) for filling down the blanks. Try something like this to filter `df <- df[df$age_column == "Age>50" , ]` where df is a data frame.

Comment: It's not very clear what type of object is your data. Can you please post the result of `dput(head(yourdata))`?

Comment: The result:
structure(c("ALABAMA", "", "ALASKA", "", "ARIZONA", "", "Under 18", 
"Total all ages", "Under 18", "Total all ages", "Under 18", "Total all ages", 
"0", "1", "10", "87", "46", "303", "0", "0", "0", "36", "6", 
"855", "84,843", "", "469,145", "", "6,303,555", ""), .Dim = c(6L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("State", "", "Rape3", "Prostitution and\ncommercialized\nvice", 
"2014\nestimated \npopulation")))

Comment: It would make more sense to use a `data.frame` for those data. What you've shown us is a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a **column header Age**

Supposing your data is called **MyDataFrame**

You could use for example:

```
# Load required package zoo
if(library("zoo", logical.return=TRUE, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)==FALSE){
  install.packages("zoo")
} else{require("zoo") }

MyDataFrame$Age<-na.locf(MyDataFrame$Age, na.rm=FALSE)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question (or at least my understanding of it). OP wants to fill the state names down.

Comment: Oh I see.Have you look at na.locf() from the package zoo?

Comment: Side note: you can replace all that `library` stuff with `if(!require(zoo))`.

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(structure(c("ALABAMA", "", "ALASKA", "", "ARIZONA", "", "Under 18", "Total all ages", "Under 18", "Total all ages", "Under 18", "Total all ages", "0", "1", "10", "87", "46", "303", "0", "0", "0", "36", "6", "855", "84,843", "", "469,145", "", "6,303,555", ""), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("State", "", "Rape3", "Prostitution and\ncommercialized\nvice", "2014\nestimated \npopulation"))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df)[5] <- "est_pop"
df$est_pop[df$est_pop == ""] <- NA
df$State[df$State == ""] <- NA

library(zoo)

df$State   <- na.locf(df$State,na.rm = TRUE)
df$est_pop <- na.locf(df$est_pop,na.rm = TRUE)
df <- df[df$V2 == "Total all ages" , ]
```