# add duplicate rows to R dataframe based on sequence

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataframe needs to be expanded

```
df1<-structure(list(TotalTime = c(0, 15, 16, 23, 24, 29), PhaseName = structure(c(1L,1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B","C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("TotalTime", "Phase"), row.names = c(NA,  6L), class = "data.frame")
```

df1:

```
  TotalTime Phase
1         0     A
2        15     A
3        16     B
4        23     B
5        24     B
6        29     C
```

So that it becomes the following dataframe with rows that are duplicated based on TotalTime, however TotalTime should be filled in for every number (second).  (I put ... in the example to reduce space, but should be filled with 6,7,8,9-15 etc.) :

```
    TotalTime   Phase
1   0   A
2   1   A
3   2   A
4   3   A
5   4   A
6   5   A
    ..  
16  15  A
17  16  B
18  17  B
    ..  B
24  23  B
25  24  B
26  25  B
27  26  B
28  27  B
29  28  B
30  29  C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using both packages `zoo` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
data.frame(TotalTime=0:max(df1$TotalTime)) %>% left_join(df1) %>% na.locf
```

It first creates a data.frame that has the hole sequence from 0 to 29 (here) and merges it with your data. Then I simply do a "last observation carried forward" imputation on the missing values created by the merge.

It can also be done with the library `data.table` like this: (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14844057/3871924) that I adapted:

```
library(data.table)
df1 = data.table(df1, key="TotalTime")
df2=data.table(TotalTime=0:max(df1$TotalTime))
df1[df2, roll=T]
```

Comment: The first solution could also be done without dplyr by using `merge` like  this:`na.locf(merge(data.frame(TotalTime=0:max(df1$TotalTime)), df1, all.x = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done with [`dplyr`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) with [`tidyr`](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% do(data.frame(TotalTime = first(.$TotalTime):last(.$TotalTime))) %>%
    left_join(df1, by="TotalTime") %>%
    fill(Phase)
```

#### Output:

```
 TotalTime Phase
  0        A    
  1        A    
  2        A    
  3        A    
  4        A    
  5        A    
  6        A    
  7        A    
  8        A    
  9        A    
 10        A    
 11        A    
 12        A    
 13        A    
 14        A    
 15        A    
 16        B    
 17        B    
 18        B    
 19        B    
 20        B    
 21        B    
 22        B    
 23        B    
 24        B    
 25        B    
 26        B    
 27        B    
 28        B    
 29        C
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to see a base R solution.

```
phases <- with(aggregate(TotalTime~Phase, df1, FUN=min),
               rep(Phase, c(diff(TotalTime),
                            max(df1$TotalTime[df1$Phase == tail(Phase, 1)]) -
                            min(df1$TotalTime[df1$Phase == tail(Phase, 1)])+1)))
```

The main "trick" here is in that the second argument of `rep` can be a vector, which then repeats each element of the first argument that many times. The second argument is constructed using the difference of the minimum values of each phase `diff(TotalTime)` and concatenating the difference of the min and max value (+1) of the final phase level (here, "C"). The minimum values are found with `aggregate`, and I use `with` to simplify notation.

The result can then be fed to the `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(period=seq_len(length(phases))-1, phase=phases)
   period phase
1       0     A
2       1     A
3       2     A
4       3     A
5       4     A
6       5     A
7       6     A
8       7     A
9       8     A
10      9     A
11     10     A
12     11     A
13     12     A
14     13     A
15     14     A
16     15     A
17     16     B
18     17     B
19     18     B
20     19     B
21     20     B
22     21     B
23     22     B
24     23     B
25     24     B
26     25     B
27     26     B
28     27     B
29     28     B
30     29     C
```